# Information gain, mutual information and related measures

Tags: information-theory

[Andrew More](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~awm/) [defines](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/infogain11.pdf) information gain as:

$IG(Y|X) = H(Y) - H(Y|X)$

where $H(Y|X)$ is the [conditional entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy). However, Wikipedia calls the above quantity [mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).

Wikipedia on the other hand defines [information gain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain) as the Kullback–Leibler divergence (aka information divergence or relative entropy) between two random variables:

$D_{KL}(P||Q) = H(P,Q) - H(P)$

where $H(P,Q)$ is defined as the [cross-entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy).

These two definitions seem to be inconsistent with each other.

I have also seen other authors talking about two additional related concepts, namely  differential entropy and relative information gain.

What is the precise definition or relationship between these quantities? Is there a good text book that covers them all?

- Information gain
- Mutual information
- Cross entropy
- Conditional entropy
- Differential entropy
- Relative information gain

Comment: To further add to confusion, note that the notation you used for cross entropy is also the same notation used for the joint entropy.  I've used $H^x(P, Q)$ for the cross-entropy to avoid confusing myself, but that's for my benefit and I've never seen that notation elsewhere.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think that calling the Kullback-Leibler divergence "information gain" is non-standard.

The first definition is standard.

EDIT: However, $H(Y)−H(Y|X)$ can also be called mutual information.

Note that I don't think you will find any scientific discipline that really has a standardized, precise, and consistent naming scheme. So you will always have to look at the formulae, because they will generally give you a better idea.

Textbooks:
see ["Good introduction into different kinds of entropy"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322/good-introduction-into-different-kinds-of-entropy).

Also:
Cosma Shalizi: Methods and Techniques of Complex Systems Science: An Overview, chapter 1 (pp. 33--114) in Thomas S. Deisboeck and J. Yasha Kresh (eds.), Complex Systems Science in Biomedicine
http://arxiv.org/abs/nlin.AO/0307015

Robert M. Gray: Entropy and Information Theory
http://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/it.html

David MacKay: Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms
http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/mackay/itila/book.html

also, ["What is “entropy and information gain”?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859554/what-is-entropy-and-information-gain)

Comment: Thanks @wolf. I'm inclined to accept this answer. If the first definition is standard, how would you define mutual information?

Comment: sorry. the first quantity, $IG(Y|X)=H(Y)−H(Y|X)$ is also often called mutual information. That's a case of inconsistent naming. As I said, I don't think there is any consistent, unambiguous, one-to-one correspondence of concepts and names. E.g. "mutual information" or "info gain" is a special case of K-L divergence, so that that wikipedia article is not that far off.

Answer (score 7):

The Kullback-Leiber Divergence between $p(X,Y)$ and $P(X)P(Y)$ is the same as mutual information, which can be easily derived:

$$
\begin{align}
I(X; Y)  &= H(Y) - H(Y \mid X)\\
&= - \sum_y p(y) \log p(y) + \sum_{x,y} p(x) p(y\mid x) \log p(y\mid x)\\
&= \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log{p(y\mid x)} - \sum_{y} \left(\sum_{x}p(x,y)\right) \log p(y)\\
&= \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log{p(y\mid x)} - \sum_{x,y}p(x, y) \log p(y)\\
&= \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log \frac{p(y\mid x)}{p(y)}\\
&= \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log \frac{p(y\mid x)p(x)}{p(y)p(x)}\\
&= \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log \frac{p(x, y)}{p(y)p(x)}\\
&= \mathcal D_{KL} (P(X,Y)\mid\mid P(X)P(Y))
\end{align}
$$

Note: $p(y) = \sum_x p(x,y)$

Answer (score 2):

Both definitions are correct, and consistent. I'm not sure what you find unclear as you point out multiple points that might need clarification.

**Firstly**: $MI_{Mutual Information}\equiv$ $IG_{InformationGain}\equiv I_{Information}$ are all different names for the same thing. In different  contexts one of these names may be preferable, i will call it hereon [**Information**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information).

The **second** point is the relation between the [Kullback–Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)-$D_{KL}$, and ***Information***. The Kullback–Leibler divergence is simply a measure of dissimilarity between two distributions. The **Information** can be defined in these terms of distributions' dissimilarity (see Yters' response). So information is a special case of $K_{LD}$, where $K_{LD}$ is applied to measure the difference between the actual joint distribution of two variables (which captures their **dependence**) and the hypothetical joint distribution of the same variables, were they to be **independent**. We call that quantity **Information**.

The **third** point to clarify is the inconsistent,  though standard **notation** being used, namely that $\operatorname{H} (X,Y)$ 
is both the notation for [**Joint entropy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_entropy) and for [**Cross-entropy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) as well.

So, for example, in the definition of **Information**: 
[\begin{aligned}\operatorname {I} (X;Y)&{}\equiv \mathrm {H} (X)-\mathrm {H} (X|Y)\\&{}\equiv \mathrm {H} (Y)-\mathrm {H} (Y|X)\\&{}\equiv \mathrm {H} (X)+\mathrm {H} (Y)-\mathrm {H} (X,Y)\\&{}\equiv \mathrm {H} (X,Y)-\mathrm {H} (X|Y)-\mathrm {H} (Y|X)\end{aligned}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information)
in both last lines, $\operatorname{H}(X,Y)$ is the **joint** entropy. This may seem inconsistent with the definition in the [Information gain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain) page however: 
$DKL(P||Q)=H(P,Q)−H(P)$ but you did not fail to quote the important clarification - $\operatorname{H}(P,Q)$ is being used there as the **cross**-entropy (as is the case too in the [cross entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) page).

**Joint**-entropy and **Cross**-entropy are **NOT** the same.

Check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2505015/relation-between-cross-entropy-and-joint-entropy) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373098/difference-of-notation-between-cross-entropy-and-joint-entropy) where this ambiguous notation is addressed and a unique notation for cross-entropy is offered -  $H_q(p)$

I would hope to see this notation accepted and the wiki-pages updated.

Comment: wonder why the equations are not displayed properly..

Answer (score 1):

Mutual information can be defined using Kullback-Liebler as 
\begin{align*}
I(X;Y) = D_{KL}(p(x,y)||p(x)p(y)).
\end{align*}