# Feature Selection: Information Gain VS Mutual Information

Tags: classification, feature-selection, information-theory, mutual-information

Setting: Multi-class classification problem with discrete nominal features.

There are many references mentioning the use of `IG`(Information Gain) and `MI` (Mutual Information) as measure of feature relevancy for filter-based feature selection. However, from the information-theoretic viewpoint it's not completely clear to me what is the difference between these two (and if there is any):

```
IG(X,Y) ?=? MI(X,Y) = H(X)-H(X|Y) = H(Y)-H(Y|X) = H(X) + H(Y) - H(X,Y) = ...
```

Notes:

- There are many ways to estimate `MI` either in Matlab, R or even by hand with toy example. However, I couldn't find a single reference mentioning **both** measures and the differences between them.
- My calculation (and understanding) of `MI` for discrete features returns the expected results and match existing `MI` f-ns (in R, Matlab). However, Weka has a f-n `InfoGainAttributeEval`:
  http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/attributeSelection/InfoGainAttributeEval.html, 
  which produces `IG` measure that is not equal to `MI` for the same data.
- There are some similar questions in SE forums and all suggest equivalence of IG and MI (e.g. [Information gain, mutual information and related measures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13389/information-gain-mutual-information-and-related-measures)). In that case - how IG is calculated in Weka and why it doesn't match MI?
- Weka's IG is available from http://featureselection.asu.edu/documentation/infogain.htm in the context of feature selection

**ANSWER:**

Please see accepted answer below. There is no indication that `MI` and `IG` have different meaning in context of information theory - they are the same measures.

Regarding WEKA and different results. I have used Feature Selection package, which **always** assumed continuous attributes and therefore Weka's discretization was applied before computing Information Gain. Running IG directly from WEKA without discretization, produced the result equivalent to MI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are identically the same.

If $X$ is a nominal feature with $k$ different values and $C$ is your target class with $m$ classes.

\begin{align}
\mbox{MI} &= \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^m P(x_i,c_j)\log \frac{P(x_i,c_j)}{P(x_i)P(c_j)}\\
&=-\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^m P(x_i,c_j)\log P(c_j)  + \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^m P(c_j|x_i)P(x_i)\log P(c_j|x_i)\\
&= -\sum_{j=1}^m P(c_j)\log P(c_j)  + \sum_{i=1}^kP(x_i)\sum_{j=1}^m P(c_j|x_i)\log P(c_j|x_i)\\
&= H(C) - H(C|X) = \mbox{IG}
\end{align}

This is a case of inconsistent naming. You might want to have a look at this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13389/information-gain-mutual-information-and-related-measures) too.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm thinking this way too - as I wrote, math tells exact equivalence. Are you familiar with Weka? I'm wondering where is the discrepancy coming from.

Comment: I guess the discrepancy originated from the first articles on decision trees: about ID3 and C4.5. It was appealing to maximize the information gain to the class due to a split according to a feature. Then this term started to be commonly used in machine learning. However this is just my guess.

Comment: That is good to know! It seems that it can be concluded that it is just a matter of ambiguous naming. The only open question is how Weka produces different results

Comment: What are you comparing weka with? are all features categorical with no missing values?

Comment: Yes, all categorical, clean. I'm just taking some toy examples, so I can verify the results by hand as well - and they do not match with Weka..
Also, I was able to find couple source (not sure how respectful they are) but they mention IG and MI as different measures:
http://www.slideshare.net/guo_dong/feature-selection
http://doras.dcu.ie/16194/2/A_Study_on_Mutual_Information-based_Feature_Selection_for_Text_Categorization.pdf
http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-29075-6_11
http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v10/sanasam10a/sanasam10a.pdf

Comment: I just figured out that in these references the authors do not use Mutual Information but actually something called pointwise mutual information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information. Maybe try to post your examples here and the correspondent Weka outcome.

Comment: Thanks, Simone - it's resolved. Please see update in the question