# Information gain and mutual information: different or equal?

Tags: classification, feature-selection, information-theory, mutual-information, sentiment-analysis

I'm very confused about the difference between Information gain and mutual information. to make it even more confusing is that I can find both sources defining them as identical and other which explain their differences:

#### *Sources stating Information gain and Mutual information are the same*

- [Feature Selection: Information Gain VS Mutual Information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116679/feature-selection-information-gain-vs-mutual-information)
- *An introduction to information retrieval*: "Show that mutual information and information gain are equivalent", page 285, exercise 13.13.
- It is thus known as the information gain, or more commonly the mutual information between X and Y" --> *CS769 Spring 2010 Advanced Natural Language Processing, "Information Theory", lecturer: Xiaojin Zhu*
- "Information gain is also called expected mutual
  information"  --> *"Feature Selection Methods for Text Classification"*,
  Nicolette Nicolosi,
  [http://www.cs.rit.edu/~nan2563/feature_selection.pdf](http://www.cs.rit.edu/%7Enan2563/feature_selection.pdf)

#### *Sources stating they're different:*

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833713/equality-of-information-gain-and-mutual-information
- yang --> *"A comparative study on Feature Selection in Text Categorization"* --> they are treated separately and  mutual information is even discarded because it performs very bad compared to IG
- citing yang --> *"An Extensive Empirical Study of
  Feature Selection Metrics for Text Classification"* -- http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/forman03a/forman03a_full.pdf

#### *Sources that are confused*

- http://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_difference_between_mutual_information_and_information_gain

I could still find other sources defending opposite thesis but I think these are enough. Can anyone enlighten me about the real difference / equality of these two measures?

### EDIT: other related question

[Information gain, mutual information and related measures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13389/information-gain-mutual-information-and-related-measures?rq=1)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two types of Mutual Information:

- *Pointwise* Mutual Information and
- *Expected* Mutual Information

The *pointwise* Mutual Information between the values of two random variables can be defined as:
$$
pMI(x;y) := \log \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)} 
$$

The *expected* Mutual Information between two random variables $X$ and $Y$ can be defined as as the Kullback-Leiber Divergence between $p(X,Y)$ and $p(X)p(Y)$:
$$
eMI(X;Y) := \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log \frac{p(x, y)}{p(x)p(y)}
$$

Sometimes you find the definition of Information Gain as $I(X; Y)  := H(Y) - H(Y \mid X)$ with the Entropy $H(Y)$ and the conditional entropy $H(Y\mid X)$ 
, so

$$
\begin{align}
I(X; Y)  &= H(Y) - H(Y \mid X)\\
&= - \sum_y p(y) \log p(y) + \sum_{x,y} p(x) p(y\mid x) \log p(y\mid x)\\
&= \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log{p(y\mid x)} - \sum_{y} \left(\sum_{x}p(x,y)\right) \log p(y)\\
&= \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log{p(y\mid x)} - \sum_{x,y}p(x, y) \log p(y)\\
&= \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log \frac{p(y\mid x)}{p(y)}\\
&= \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log \frac{p(y\mid x)p(x)}{p(y)p(x)}\\
&= \sum_{x,y} p(x, y) \log \frac{p(x, y)}{p(y)p(x)}\\
&= eMI(X;Y)
\end{align}
$$

Note: $p(y) = \sum_x p(x,y)$

So expected Mutual Information and Information Gain are the same (with both definitions above).

Comment: Note on edit: There was a mistake in the original derivation.

Comment: is $I(X;Y) = H(X) + H(Y) - H(X,Y)$ point-wise or expected mutual information?

Answer (score 5):

"Information gain" seems to be an overloaded name that corresponds to multiple formulas. The non-ambiguous names appear to be:

1. The mutual information linking two random variables X and Y:

$$ MI(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y) - H(X,Y) = H(Y) - H(Y|X) = H(X) - H(X|Y) $$

where $H$ is the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition) of the random variable, and

2. the Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence, which measures the difference between two probability laws or probability density functions:

$$ KL(p,q) = \int p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx. $$

These two quantities are linked. After straightforward manipulations from $ MI(X,Y) = H(Y) - H(Y|X)$, we find:

$$ MI(X,Y) = \int p(x) KL(P(Y=y|X=x) | P(Y=y)) dx, $$

where the right hand side is the average KL divergence between a random variable's marginal and conditional distributions.