# Information Value Definition on Siddiqui "Credit Risk Scorecards" Book

Tags: mutual-information, credit-scoring

I was studying about information value, and saw the definition on "Siddiqui, Credit Risk Scorecards". I'm searchin for some references on why the formula there is that way, and also for  the thresholds he assumes for variable selection, can someone help me? At first I assumed that information value was almost the same as mutual information, but the formulas don't match ( i tried both pointwise mututal information and expected mutual information as described here:[Information gain and mutual information: different or equal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163463/information-gain-and-mutual-information-different-or-equal)). The definition on the book is:

$$
\sum_i (DistrGood_i - DistrBad_i) ∗ ln\frac{DistrGood_i}{DistrBad_i} 
$$