# Are Mutual Information and Kullback–Leibler divergence equivalent?

Tags: kullback-leibler, mutual-information

From my readings, I understand that:

1. Mutual information $\mathit{(MI)}$ is a metric as it meets the triangle inequality, non-negativity, indiscernability and symmetry criteria.
2. The Kullback–Leibler divergence $\mathit{(D_{KL})}$ is ***not*** a metric as it does not obey the triangle inequality

However, one answer on Cross Validated ([Information gain, mutual information and related measures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13389/information-gain-mutual-information-and-related-measures)) [the second answer], it was shown that mutual information and Kullback–Leibler divergence are equivalent.  How can this be given that $\mathit{MI}$ is a metric and $\mathit{D_{KL}}$ is not?  I can only assume that I am missing something here.

Comment: mutual information is not a metric. Variation of information is a metric

Comment: @develarist - thanks for this. This is very interesting as going by a Google search, it is clear that mutual information is treated as a metric by some data analysts.

Comment: You may be interested in the Christopher Olah - Visual Information Theory post (https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-09-Visual-Information/). He relates mutual information, kl diveregence and other concepts with each other with some visual aids.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Mutual information is not a metric. A metric $d$ satisfies the identity of indiscernibles: $d(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $x = y$. This is not true of mutual information, which behaves in the opposite manner--zero mutual information implies that two random variables are independent (as far from identical as you can get). And, if two random variables are identical, they have *maximal* mutual information (as far from zero as you can get).

You're correct that KL divergence is not a metric. It's not symmetric and doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality.

Mutual information and KL divergence are not equivalent. However, the mutual information $I(X, Y)$ between random variables $X$ and $Y$ is given by the KL divergence between the joint distribution $p_{XY}$ and the product of the marginal distributions $p_X \otimes p_Y$ (what the joint distribution *would* be if $X$ and $Y$ were independent).

$$I(X, Y) = D_{KL}(p_{XY} \parallel p_X \otimes p_Y)$$

Although mutual information is not itself a metric, there are metrics based on it. For example, the [variation of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_information):

$$VI(X, Y) = H(X, Y) - I(X, Y) = H(X) + H(Y) - 2 I(X, Y)$$

where $H(X)$ and $H(Y)$ are the marginal entropies and $H(X, Y)$ is the joint entropy.

Comment: This is ***most*** interesting as when I type the absolute phrase "mutual information in a metric" into Google, I get something like "about 367,000 results".  Some 103 references on Google Scholar also return the use the phrase.  So clearly there is some interpretation that MI is being treated as a metric.

Comment: @MurrayB By "metric", I mean a formal [distance metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)), satisfying the conditions you mentioned in the question (symmetry, triangle inequality,  identity of indiscernibles). However, it's quite common to use the word "metric" more informally, to describe a way of measuring or quantifying something. I suspect this is probably what's happening in your google results.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was assuming the same. The misuse of terms makes understanding maths, statistics and data analysis all the more challenging.

Comment: Can you provide the proof for the identity?